# Docker at High Sierra not starting nginx at Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, nginx, macos-sierra

My Docker Desktop is showing a different status from the Terminal.

Terminal screen

```
Creating webroker_docker-in-docker_1 ... done
Creating webroker_mysql_1            ... done
Creating webroker_workspace_1        ... done
Creating webroker_php-fpm_1          ... done
Creating webroker_nginx_1            ... done
```

But at the Desktop App, shows that nginx is not running, as the image attached:

[image: My Docker Desktop App]

And, of course, can't reach via browser at http://localhost

Any ideas?

Comment: it may be created, but crashed soon after - you can get the same output with `docker ps` and inspect the container with `docker logs`

Comment: Indeed. There is just four items and should be five! That ```webroker_nginx_1``` don't appear at the result after ```docker ps```.  And the ```docker logs webroker_nginx_1``` shows: ```nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf:3```two times. But I can't see the problem yet

Comment: I think the problem is in the ```/etc/nginx/sites-avaiable/desfalt.conf```, right?

Comment: The problem is that this file is inside that ```webroker_nginx_1``` item and how it is not running, can't have access…